# Background image with php

Tags: php

I would like to put an background and all other text would be on it.

I put this code but won't work.

```
<div style="background-image:url(<?php echo $imageUrl?>) no-repeat center center fixed">
</div>
<?php
$imageUrl = 'http://azcombats.com/bg.jpg';
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare the $imageUrl variable before you use it.

```
<?php
$imageUrl = 'http://azcombats.com/bg.jpg';
?>
<div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background:url(<?php echo $imageUrl?>) no-repeat center center fixed">
</div>
```

Comment: @DariusRay Your CSS is incorrect, background-image should be background, and as mario.klump said, you need to specify a size on the div. Updated my example.

Comment: it should be
<?php
$imageUrl = 'http://azcombats.com/bg.jpg'
?>
<div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background:url('<?php echo $imageUrl?>') no-repeat center center fixed">
</div>.

put single quotes around background url

Comment: @VMcreator the quotes are not mandatory [w3 source](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-uri)

Comment: @beije Well, this code should be working by now.. if not yet.. then OP should put a fixed height and width like in 'px'. +1

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see the image because the height and the width of the div container is zero (because it has no content). Please set the height and the width of the div container to the dimensions of the image.